# Como filtrar a entrada de dados de um formulário para o Banco de Dados?

Tags: php, funções

Tenho uma função para filtrar dados de entrada para enviar ao banco de dados, estive olhando agora a pouco e pensei que ainda tem o que melhorar, o padrão que uso é UTF_8, os dados vem de formulários e são tratados para serem gravados no mysql.

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('filtra_var') ){
    function filtra_var($var) {
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = addslashes($var);
        $var = htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $var = fgetss($var);
        return $var;
    }
}
?>
```

No SQL também faço uso de

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$var);
```

Alguma recomendação de como melhorar a proteção contra injection/maliciosos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PHP já existem funções nativas que trabalham melhor para filtrar entradas de dados.

As funções `filter_*` permitem uma série de validações e sanitizers onde é possível fazer praticamente tudo.

Segue a lista dos possíveis filtros:

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

É possível importar diretamente das variáveis de `$_POST` e `$_GET` a partir do [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) ou até mesmo importar e limpar o formulário inteiro com [`filter_input_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php). Na documentação do PHP temos o seguinte exemplo:

```
<?php

/* dados no post:
$_POST = array(
    'product_id'    => 'libgd<script>',
    'component'     => '10',
    'versions'      => '2.0.33',
    'testscalar'    => array('2', '23', '10', '12'),
    'testarray'     => '2',
);
*/

$args = array(
    'product_id'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'component'    => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'     => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
                            'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 10)
                           ),
    'versions'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'doesnotexist' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'testscalar'   => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                           ),
    'testarray'    => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
                           )

);

$myinputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

var_dump($myinputs);
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
array(6) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "libgd%3Cscript%3E"
  }
  ["component"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
  }
  ["versions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "2.0.33"
  }
  ["doesnotexist"]=>
  NULL
  ["testscalar"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["testarray"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Depois do input limpo, uma próxima camada como você comentou é a inserção no banco. A forma mais otimizada para trabalhar com isso é com *[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)*. Eles já aplicam o escape de strings deixando seu código mais simples. Seu código sairia disso:

```
$titulo = mysql_real_escape_string($titulo);
$autor_livro = mysql_real_escape_string($autor_livro);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_livro VALUES (NULL, '$titulo', '$autor_livro')");
```

Para isso:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_livro VALUES (NULL, :titulo, :autor_livro)");
$stmt->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
$stmt->bindParam(':autor_livro', $autor_livro);

$stmt->execute();
```

Essa é uma introdução bem rápida sobre esses assuntos, mas fica como uma referencia para conhecer como fazer e como acontece por debaixo dos panos. Tudo isso e mais algumas coisas são abstraídos por frameworks como Laravel, Symfony, para que assim você não precise se preocupar em implementar tudo isso.

Comment: Obrigado gmsantos, vou praticar ainda mais com todas as dicas.