# Undefined property: DatePeriod::$format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Estou fazendo um sistema que cadastre um conjunto de datas via $_POST. Quero inserir no banco de dados o intervalo criado abaixo via datetime. Porém quando executo aparece a mensagem acima. Como proceder? O erro aparece na instrução $sql.

```
    $start = new DateTime($_POST["data1"]); //nova data começo
    $end = new DateTime($_POST["data2"]); // final da data

    $interval = new DateInterval("P1D"); //intervalo de datas no periodo de um dia

    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end); //periodo no começo da data, intervalo e final da data

    try
    {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php","root","");
        $connection->exec("set_names_utf8");
    }
    catch(PDOExeption $e)
    {
        echo "Erro" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO datas(datas) VALUES('$period->format('d-m-Y')')";
    $x = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $x->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro diz que não é possível utilizar o método `format`. Você está utilizando o objeto da forma errada. Verifique na documentação do [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) os métodos disponíveis:

```
DatePeriod implements Traversable {

    /* Constants */
    const integer EXCLUDE_START_DATE = 1 ;

    /* Properties */
    public integer $recurrences ;
    public boolean $include_start_date ;
    public DateTimeInterface $start ;
    public DateTimeInterface $current ;
    public DateTimeInterface $end ;
    public DateInterval $interval ;

    /* Methods */
    public __construct ( DateTimeInterface $start , DateInterval $interval , int $recurrences [, int $options ] )
    public __construct ( DateTimeInterface $start , DateInterval $interval , DateTimeInterface $end [, int $options ] )
    public __construct ( string $isostr [, int $options ] )
    public getDateInterval ( void ) : DateInterval
    public getEndDate ( void ) : DateTimeInterface
    public getRecurrences ( void ) : int
    public getStartDate ( void ) : DateTimeInterface
}
```

O que você pode estar tentando fazer é inserir ambas as datas no banco. Se for isso, você pode utilizar `$period->getStartDate()->format('...')` e `$period->getEndDate()->format('...')`.

Existem outros problemas com seu código. Ele está sujeito a SQL injection e é importante você tratar as entradas de dados do seu sistema, e melhorar como você constroi suas queries. As perguntas abaixo vão te ajudar:

- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-sql-no-meu-c%c3%b3digo-php)
- [Como filtrar a entrada de dados de um formulário para o Banco de Dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360908/como-filtrar-a-entrada-de-dados-de-um-formul%c3%a1rio-para-o-banco-de-dados/360911#360911)